# How do I a parse JSON document with dynamic keys in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON doc that looks something like this:

```
{   
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": {
    "random_value": {
       "keyX": {
          "keyY": "valueY",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key names random_value keeps changing and I would like to retrieve valueY. How do I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Is `random_value` always the only key in the `key2` object?

Comment: Please give an example of input and desired output

Comment: If the `random_value` dict isn't the only item in the `"key2"` dict, are there any other items in `"key2"` that contain a `"keyX"` dict?

Comment: The solution by @Terry worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your json is in `json` (variable)

With a for loop you can retrieve the random values:

```
for value in json['key2']:
```

where value is 'random_value' in this case, but if you have more values it will just keep looping. Then you can do something like this (inside the for loop):

```
json['key2'][value]['keyX']['keyY']
```

So your code looks something like this: (This is just printing the value)

```
json = # Your json defined in your post

for value in json['key2']:
    print(json['key2'][value]['keyX']['keyY'])
```

Comment: Why would you use `json` as a variable name? That conflicts with the name of the  `json` module, and surely any (sane) Python program that deals with JSON imports that module.

Comment: No problem, @PM2Ring is right json isn't a good variable name so make sure to change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `json` library:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_string = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": {"random_value": {"keyX": {"keyY": "valueY"}}}}'
>>> parsed = json.loads(my_string)
>>> parsed["key1"]
value1
>>> parsed["key2"].keys()[0]["keyX"]["keyY"]
valueY
```

What it does: First, you convert the json dataset into a dict by using `json.loads()`.

Then you can get values only by passing the key names:

```
>>> parsed["key1"]
value1
```

With converting the dict into a list, you can get values by passing an index:

```
>>> parsed.keys()["key2"][0]["keyX"]["keyY"]
valueY
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This gives me:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score -1):

```
 mainDict=   {   
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": {"random_value":{"keyx":{"keyy": "valuey"}}}}

  tempdict1 = maindict['key2']
  temparray1 = tempdict1.values()
  tempdict2 = temparray[0]
  temparray2 = tempdict2.values()
  tempdict3 = temparray2[0]
  valuey = tempdict3['keyy']
```

this will work

Comment: that indentation is a mess (besides that, camelCase in python is an awful thing ;))